# how DOM is manipulated by jquery in this code?

Tags: jquery

Look the following jquery code:

```
var index = 0;
$(document).ready(
    $("p").on("click", function () {
        $("p").after($("<p>you have clicked "+(++index).toString()+" times on this text </p>"));
        $("p").first().remove();
        console.log(index);
    })
);
```

Initially there is only a `p` tag in HTML (nothing else) so I expect that the first time the user clicks on the text(initial paragraph text) `you have clicked 1 times on the text` will appear and subsequently the index will increase and the text will be changed for every click..
But it doesn't work in this way on first click, it puts a `p` tag in DOM (as I can see in chrome inspect element) but it doesn't work after that **why**?

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrkzP/ It needs the parent to update the listeners

Comment: OK guys you all says event delegation let me google what is **event delegation**...

Comment: @VVV If you are using it just to increment click value you dont need to do all these. I have an answer probably you can check it out. Event delegation, removing adding element for this is an overkill according to me.

Comment: @PSL got some idea about event delegation from your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to what all the other experts are saying ...

This part runs at document load:

```
$("p").on("click" ...
```

And this part runs when they click on the `<p>` elements present at that time:

```
    $("p").after($("<p>you have clicked "+(++index).toString()+" times on this text </p>"));
    $("p").first().remove();
    console.log(index);
```

But you added new `<p>` elements and they have no click listeners.

The other answers are showing how to add the click handler function higher up the DOM hierarchy. Do it the way they describe. Then the click event 'bubbles' up from where it happened and jQuery figures out if its on the `<p>` and runs the handler function.

Another alternative is to give the function a name and, whenever you add a `<p>` then add a click listener to it. So you will reference the function inside the function.

Someone might comment on which is "better." In the one, the events go bubbline around and jQuery has to traverse the DOM looking for `<p>` elements. In the other, you keep adding click event listeners over and over.

There are other ways to do this that are much better. (I like just putting the count in its own `<span>` element and changing out that text on each click.)

Comment: OK oK.. I think i got the point you all were trying to say it is that that, when make a listner with `$("p").on...` then i m attaching it specifically with my initial HTML p element. since i remove it from DOM after first click hence the p element which generated event onclick is not avilable so it doesn't work anymore.. please guys tell me am i getting it correct???

Comment: That's it. You got it. The solutions are everywhere here.

Comment: By changing my event listner to `$(document).on("click", "p", function(){...` i am taking it to document level so it will work with all the p tags that are inside document

Answer (score 4):

It does not work because you are not using the signature of `.on()` that utilizes event delegation. Change it to this and it should work fine:

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function () {
```

You should replace `document` with whatever static container is the closest container to the `p` tags.

Check out [jqFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) for information about event delegation.

Comment: The key to your answer is how you put it on an ancestor element to the `<p>` that OP cares about.

Answer (score 2):

Cause when the event is bound , the element is still non-existent on the page..

When the script that attaches the events is executed ,  elements which exist on the page are given the handlers..

So when you click the first time , the click event for that element is executed, then you remove the element to which the event is bound. Now you click the `p` element which is a new element that was added later to the `DOM` .

**You need to delegate the event**

```
 $("body").on("click", "p" function () {
```

Comment: It exists ... otherwise, the first click wouldn't work ;-)  It doesn't exist after the first click because the element with the listener is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the new DOM elements do not have the click event the first one had.

You need to use `$(document).on("click", "p", function () { });` instead.

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ3H3/)**